# Pull data from multiple records into one row

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, filemaker

I want to pull out the data from multiple records and insert them into different fields of a single record in another table. The work I am doing requires me to pull the `cw_cat_total` field(which is the sum of all the assignments corresponding to a particular category of assignment and put the appropriate data into the fields of another table.

The `cw_cat_total` field was calculated from a self-joined relationship. I just could not figure out how to get the individual component into the different columns of the table in the second picture.

[image]

Can anyone Filemaker programmers help me out here?

Update:

My database certainly contains more tables. It is quite complicated (from my point of view). Below is the ER graph.

[image: ER graph of my database]

What I try to achieve is to pull the component scores into the different columns of the `results` table so that a student's assignment score may be computed with different weightings for the different category. This coursework score, together with what the student scores for the examination at each quarter(term), will then be displayed in the `reports` table.

As a side note, I am a teacher of the school (not a developer). Hence, my schema may not be what the industry normally practiced. I did read up about database normalisation and think I understand (which I may not, I'm not sure). I tried my best to design around what I think the industry practices. If my ER graph is seriously flawed that affect implementing what I want to do, please point it out so I can redesign the entire database. I will need to compute the overall results (from `results` table) base on different weighting of different terms in the report of term 4. But I think that problem is similar to this.

Comment: Can you please add more to your description? In particular, what are you trying to do and why? What does `cw_total` mean? How does it relate to the other table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Traditional Method:** (Works for FileMaker 7 onward)

Traditionally the way to do this in FileMaker is to create additional Table Occurrences of the Coursework_Results table that are related on both "_kf_resultID" and on "type".

1: On your "Results" table create a new calculation field for each type of coursework_result. Let us use "Classwork" as the example.

- Name the new field _k_Classwork
- Make the field type Calculation
- Set the calculation to be type Text
- Set the calculation to return the string "Classwork"
- Uncheck "Do not evaluate if all referenced fields are empty"

Repeat this process for every "type" in the "coursework_results" table data.

2: For each "type" make a new Table Occurrence of your "Coursework_results" table. Name it "Coursework_results_Classwork". Link it to the "Results" table in the following way:

```
Results::_kp_resultID     \____________/ Coursework_results_Classwork::_kf_resultID
Results::_k_Classwork     /            \ Coursework_results_Classwork::type
```

Repeat this process for every "type" in the "coursework_results" table data.

3: Set the calculation of "classwork_percent" to be:

```
Sum ( Coursework_results_Classwork::mark ) / Sum ( Coursework_results_Classwork::max_mark )
```

Then set up the other _percent fields similarly, based on their own newly created table occurrences. (ex: Coursework_results_Quiz::mark and Coursework_results_Project::mark)

**Execute SQL** (Works for FileMaker 12)

FileMaker 12 gives you the new ExecuteSQL step which you can use to skip setting up new schema in your database. In this case, all you would need to do is modify the "classwork_percent" field to have the calculation:

```
ExecuteSQL(
    "SELECT
        SUM(mark)
     FROM
        Coursework_results
     WHERE
        _kf_resultID = ?"; 
     ""; ""; _kp_resultID)
```

For more information check out FileMaker's page: http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.6.html

Also check out the FileMaker SQL Sugar ("@") Module for help building queries: http://www.modularfilemaker.org/2013/03/filemaker-sql-sugar/

Comment: Great answer, useful links. The ExecuteSQL is very elegant, I shall have to start using it more.

Comment: I tried the SQL method but it only shows a ? character in all my records. What went wrong?